# Integrate symfony2 app in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, symfony, integrate

I just finish an app Symfony2 and I would like to add it into a wordpress website as a "page".
I have tryed two thigs, but both of them don't work :

- Firstly, I tryed with an Iframe: The problem I have with this solution is I need to resize my iframe because its size depend of the number of results I show inside it. I'm using this js plugin to resize the iframe automaticly http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing but it doesn't work for me "because cross site scripting problem". Them I put all the code in the same server, but It's still giving me problems. The problem with this is I need to call the "iframe" by some thing like this --> iframe src = "http: // localhost....." or "../relativepath..." but wordpress tell me that path is not valid and that's not true. I guess wordpress has a especial way to use "local-host" or "relative paths".
- Second way has a very big problem: I tryed to copy all the app symfony2 code into the wordpress folder and after that I included go streith by "include file". The problem I have it's Symfony2 tell me the session is already started (by wordpress) and it stop to work.

Any ideas guys? What would you do?

Next step is try to jump thougth the window :(

Comment: Have you checked this question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10843410/1828051

Comment: You could try the second way and disable the session check in Symfony2?